# Realm 5.8.0 causes dex error under Android

Tags: android, realm

I have an Android app that is building and running fine under Realm 5.7.0. I just upgraded my gradle to 5.8.0, and the initial sync went fine, but then when I tried to execute the app to my emulator, I got this error:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\frysingg\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\jetified-realm-android-library-5.8.0.aar\c1094bb66029494e6cdb95ba0999c5a7\jars\classes.jar 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.  
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

Doing a clean, rebuild, clearing the Android Studio cache and restarting don't help. Moving back to 5.7.0 does.

Is there something else i need to do in order to use 5.8.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to add support for Java 8, place this inside the **android** block of your **build.gradle**

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Yep, that worked! for future updates, how would I have known this?

Comment: This part of the error log is the key 

**com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)**.

That means some dependency in your project needs Java 8 in order to work (Realm 5.8.0 for your case) maybe they should make the log more descriptive... but that's what we have right now.

Comment: Thanks amilcar-sr

Comment: @tfrysinger  It is explained at [https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support)

Answer (score 2):

Go to application level gradle and write this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in  app   build.gradle

```
android{
 compileOptions {
 sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  }
```